# Can a group admin remove the group creator on WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Can a group admin remove the group creator on WhatsApp? If i add a person as creator then make them admin.. can they remove me from my own group?

Answer (score 3):

The way WhatsApp works is whenever a group is created by user he is himself an admin by default and can add other people as admins. And all admins have the same privileges so basically, an admin can remove anyone from the group but the creator can not be removed unless he himself exits the group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No Admin can remove the creator. It will show (can't remove creator's name) because they created this group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is bad but true. An admin can remove anyone including creator and other admins.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever who the admin add or remove, no one, include the creator, can stop him.
Therefore, think carefully, befor promote someone as a admin.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they can. Practically, there is no difference between the creator and just another admin.